# User Defined Function for DateDiff in Excel Spreadh sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to set up a user defined function to calculate the hours worked between employee clock in and out with the following code. It worked well the `VBA` code window, but it did not show up under the Function bar on the spreadsheet. Any clue?

```
Function HoursWorked()

clockin = [b2]
clockout = [c2]

HoursWorked = Round(DateDiff("n", clockin, clockout) / 60, 2)

[d2] = HoursWorked

MsgBox HoursWorked

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how do you mean? as you can see in the picture both the funtions I have written in `VBA` [left of screen] appear in the function bar in excel

[image]

Maybe you want to try the below edited version where you don't always have to work with cells `B2`,`C2` and `D2`. I entered `=HoursWorkedv2(B2,C2)`in cell `E4`

```
Public Function HoursWorkedv2(ByVal Time1 As Date, ByVal Time2 As Date)

clockin = Time1
clockout = Time2

HoursWorkedv2 = Round(DateDiff("n", clockin, clockout) / 60, 2)


End Function
```

Comment: Hello Tyler,Thank you so much for your help, appreciated.

Comment: Now, both functions show up on under the function bar on spreadsheet. However, my method did not give correct answer. please see screen shot below. Sorry I could not paste screen shot here. I am new, would you mind showing me how to attach screen shot please?

Comment: I used 3/8/2016 9:42 as clockin and 3/8/2016 23:08 as clockout and d2=HoursWorked(B2,C2)=0, though it worked well in VBA code window.

Comment: I guess that it did not show up because the code was in Sheet1 instead of Module1. Correct? The other problem I have for user defined functions is that Step Into is not always available. Is there a way to ensure that Step Into is always there to debug functions? Thanks and best regards

Comment: 1. You cant add screenshots in comments 2.Yes, right click on your book in your VBA Project and insert a module to paste the function into the module 3. Make sure the formats are right in the sheet... B2 and C2 must be dates and make sure D2 is formatted to show decimals... As you can see in my screenshot the formula worked perfectly in cell in E2 –

Comment: Your code worked very well. I was trying to use mine as below Function myOverTime()

clockin = [b2]
clockout = [c2]

myOverTime = Round(DateDiff("n", clockin, clockout) / 60, 2)

MsgBox myOverTime


End Function, again, it worked well and got 13.43 in code window. However, when I used D2=myOvertime(B2,C2), with clockin and clockout commented out, I got #VALUE!. B2 and C2 were entered as date same as in your spreadsheet. Would you please help me to find out why #Value! best regards

Comment: The function you outlined in your last comment is very different to one I supplied. Of course myOverTime(b2,c2) is not going to work because myOverTime() without any ByVals means you cant pass cells through to formula. Before modifying the formula anymore please google VBA function basics. If the original question has been answered please mark the question as answered  (http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/user-defined-function.html)

Comment: there should be a tick under up and votes icon near the top left of the question